# Relatório JasperReports com múltiplos parâmetros

Tags: mysql, jsf, primefaces, jasper-reports

Tenho um relatório no `JasperReports`, está funcionando corretamente. Entretanto da forma em que está, passo apenas um parêmetro de cada `tipo`da página jsf para o relatório, a tela é conforme a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu preciso agora é, poder enviar mais de um `cliente` , por exemplo, para o relatório como parâmetro. Ainda não consegui fazer. Uma idéia básica seria ter um botão ao lado da combo, que quando clicado enviaria o conteúdo desta para uma lista, algo assim e em seguida, esta lista de parâmetros enviada para o relatório. Mas não consegui implementar, então se alguém puder ajudar, obrigado.

Bean:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.hibernate.Session;

import com.rodrigo.controleacidentes.model.Cliente;
import com.rodrigo.controleacidentes.model.StatusEntrada;
import com.rodrigo.controleacidentes.util.jsf.FacesUtil;
import com.rodrigo.controleacidentes.util.report.ExecutorRelatorioPdf;
import com.rodrigo.controleacidentes.util.report.ExecutorRelatorioXls;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class RelatorioEntradasBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Date dataInicio;
    private Date dataFim;
    private Cliente cliente;
    private StatusEntrada statusEntrada;

    public StatusEntrada getStatusEntrada() {
        return statusEntrada;
    }

    public void setStatusEntrada(StatusEntrada statusEntrada) {
        this.statusEntrada = statusEntrada;
    }

    public void teste(StatusEntrada st) {
        // StatusEntrada entrada = StatusEntrada.valueOf(st);
        System.out.println("TESTE: " + st);
    }

    @Inject
    private FacesContext facesContext;

    @Inject
    private HttpServletResponse response;

    @Inject
    private EntityManager manager;

    public void emitirXls() {
        Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<>();
        parametros.put("data_inicio", this.dataInicio);
        parametros.put("data_fim", this.dataFim);
        if (cliente != null) {

            System.out.println("TESTE: " + cliente.getNome());
            parametros.put("nome_cliente", cliente.getNome());
        }
        if (statusEntrada != null) {
            System.out.println("TESTE :" + statusEntrada.getDescricao());
            parametros.put("status_entrada", statusEntrada.getDescricao());

        }

        ExecutorRelatorioXls executor = new ExecutorRelatorioXls("/relatorios/RelatorioEntradasNome.jasper",
                this.response, parametros, "Relatório Entradas.xls");

        Session session = manager.unwrap(Session.class);
        session.doWork(executor);

        if (executor.isRelatorioGerado()) {
            facesContext.responseComplete();
        } else {
            FacesUtil.addErrorMessage("A execução do relatório não retornou dados.");
        }
    }

    public void emitirPdf() {
        Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<>();
        parametros.put("data_inicio", this.dataInicio);
        parametros.put("data_fim", this.dataFim);
        parametros.put("nome_cliente", this.cliente);

        ExecutorRelatorioPdf executor = new ExecutorRelatorioPdf("/relatorios/RelatorioEntradasNome.jasper",
                this.response, parametros, "Relatório Entradas.pdf");

        Session session = manager.unwrap(Session.class);
        session.doWork(executor);

        if (executor.isRelatorioGerado()) {
            facesContext.responseComplete();
        } else {
            FacesUtil.addErrorMessage("A execução do relatório não retornou dados.");
        }
    }

    @NotNull
    public Date getDataInicio() {
        return dataInicio;
    }

    public void setDataInicio(Date dataInicio) {
        this.dataInicio = dataInicio;
    }

    @NotNull
    public Date getDataFim() {
        return dataFim;
    }

    public void setDataFim(Date dataFim) {
        this.dataFim = dataFim;
    }

    @NotNull
    public Cliente getCliente() {
        return cliente;
    }

    public void setCliente(Cliente cliente) {
        this.cliente = cliente;
    }

}
```

Executor:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.hibernate.jdbc.Work;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRParameter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsExporter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsExporterParameter;

public class ExecutorRelatorioXls implements Work {

    private String caminhoRelatorio;
    private HttpServletResponse response;
    private Map<String, Object> parametros;
    private String nomeArquivoSaida;

    private boolean relatorioGerado;

    public ExecutorRelatorioXls(String caminhoRelatorio, HttpServletResponse response, Map<String, Object> parametros,
            String nomeArquivoSaida) {
        this.caminhoRelatorio = caminhoRelatorio;
        this.response = response;
        this.parametros = parametros;
        this.nomeArquivoSaida = nomeArquivoSaida;

        this.parametros.put(JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE, new Locale("pt", "BR"));
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        try {
            InputStream relatorioStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(this.caminhoRelatorio);

            JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(relatorioStream, this.parametros, connection);
            this.relatorioGerado = print.getPages().size() > 0;

            if (this.relatorioGerado) {
                JRXlsExporter exportador = new JRXlsExporter();
                exportador.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, response.getOutputStream());
                exportador.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, print);

                exportador.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_ONE_PAGE_PER_SHEET, Boolean.FALSE);
                exportador.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE);
                exportador.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, Boolean.FALSE);

                response.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "Cp1256");
                response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
                response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + this.nomeArquivoSaida + "\"");

                exportador.exportReport();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SQLException("Erro ao executar relatório " + this.caminhoRelatorio, e);
        }
    }

    public boolean isRelatorioGerado() {
        return relatorioGerado;
    }

}
```

Query no relatório:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     ocorrencia.`id` AS ocorrencia_id,
     ocorrencia.`descricao` AS ocorrencia_descricao,
     ocorrencia.`condicao_tempo` AS ocorrencia_condicao_tempo,
     ocorrencia.`data_ocorrencia` AS ocorrencia_data_ocorrencia,
     ocorrencia.`periodo_ocorrencia` AS ocorrencia_periodo_ocorrencia,
     ocorrencia.`condutor_id` AS ocorrencia_condutor_id,
     condutor.`id` AS condutor_id,
     condutor.`codigo` AS condutor_codigo,
     condutor.`nome` AS condutor_nome,
     entrada_acidente.`id` AS entrada_acidente_id,
     entrada_acidente.`data_criacao` AS entrada_acidente_data_criacao,
     entrada_acidente.`ocorrencia_id` AS entrada_acidente_ocorrencia_id,
     entrada_acidente.`valor_unitario` AS entrada_acidente_valor_unitario,
     cliente.`id` AS cliente_id,
     cliente.`nome` AS cliente_nome,
     entrada_acidente.`status` AS entrada_acidente_status
FROM
     `condutor` condutor INNER JOIN `ocorrencia` ocorrencia ON condutor.`id` = ocorrencia.`condutor_id`
     INNER JOIN `entrada_acidente` entrada_acidente ON ocorrencia.`id` = entrada_acidente.`ocorrencia_id`
     INNER JOIN `cliente` cliente ON entrada_acidente.`cliente_id` = cliente.`id`
WHERE
     entrada_acidente.`data_criacao` BETWEEN $P{data_inicio} AND $P{data_fim}
 AND cliente.`nome` = $P{nome_cliente}
 AND entrada_acidente.`status` = $P{status_entrada}
```

xhtml:

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/template/LayoutPadrao.xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <ui:define name="titulo">Relatório de entradas emitidas</ui:define>

    <ui:define name="corpo">
        <h:form id="frm">
            <h1>Relatório de entradas emitidas</h1>

            <p:messages autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />

            <p:toolbar style="margin-top: 20px">
                <p:toolbarGroup>
                    <p:commandButton value="EmitirPdf"
                        action="#{relatorioEntradasBean.emitirPdf}" ajax="false" />
                    <p:commandButton value="EmitirXls"
                        action="#{relatorioEntradasBean.emitirXls}" ajax="false" />
                </p:toolbarGroup>
            </p:toolbar>

            <p:panelGrid columns="7" id="painel"
                style="width: 100%; margin-top: 20px" columnClasses="rotulo, campo">
                <p:outputLabel value="Data de criação" />
                <h:panelGroup>
                    <p:calendar value="#{relatorioEntradasBean.dataInicio}"
                        label="Data inicial" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" size="8" />
                    <p:spacer width="8" />
                    <h:outputText value="a" />
                    <p:spacer width="8" />
                    <p:calendar value="#{relatorioEntradasBean.dataFim}"
                        label="Data final" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" size="8" />
                </h:panelGroup>
                <h:panelGroup>
                    <p:outputLabel value="Cliente" for="cliente" />
                    <p:autoComplete id="cliente" size="40" dropdown="true"
                        value="#{relatorioEntradasBean.cliente}"
                        completeMethod="#{cadastroEntradaBean.completarCliente}"
                        var="cliente" itemLabel="#{cliente.nome}" itemValue="#{cliente}"
                        forceSelection="true" />
                </h:panelGroup>


                <p:outputLabel value="Status" />
                <h:panelGroup>
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="statusEntrada"
                        value="#{relatorioEntradasBean.statusEntrada}">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{enumProviderStatus.statusEntradas}"
                            var="statusEntrada" itemValue="#{statusEntrada}"
                            itemLabel="#{statusEntrada.descricao}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </p:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Update1:

```
     //query "base"
    public String getQueryPrincipal(String queryPrincipal) {
        return queryPrincipal = "SELECT  cliente.id AS cliente_id,"
                + " cliente.doc_receita_federal AS cliente_doc_receita_federal," + "  cliente.email AS cliente_email,"
                + " cliente.nome AS cliente_nome," + "  cliente.tipo AS cliente_tipo," + "  condutor.id AS condutor_id,"
                + " condutor.codigo AS condutor_codigo," + "  condutor.nome AS condutor_nome,"
                + " despesa.id AS despesa_id," + " despesa.nome AS despesa_nome," + "   despesa.sku AS despesa_sku,"
                + " despesa.categoria_id AS despesa_categoria_id," + "  entrada_acidente.id AS entrada_acidente_id,"
                + " entrada_acidente.attach AS entrada_acidente_attach,"
                + " entrada_acidente.data_criacao AS entrada_acidente_data_criacao,"
                + " entrada_acidente.fileName AS entrada_acidente_fileName,"
                + " entrada_acidente.forma_pagamento AS entrada_acidente_forma_pagamento,"
                + " entrada_acidente.observacao AS entrada_acidente_observacao,"
                + " entrada_acidente.status AS entrada_acidente_status,"
                + " entrada_acidente.valor_desconto AS entrada_acidente_valor_desconto,"
                + " entrada_acidente.valor_total AS entrada_acidente_valor_total,"
                + " entrada_acidente.cliente_id AS entrada_acidente_cliente_id,"
                + " entrada_acidente.ocorrencia_id AS entrada_acidente_ocorrencia_id,"
                + " entrada_acidente.vendedor_id AS entrada_acidente_vendedor_id,"
                + " entrada_acidente.valor_unitario AS entrada_acidente_valor_unitario,"
                + " entrada_acidente.quantidade AS entrada_acidente_quantidade,"
                + " item_despesa.id AS item_despesa_id," + "  item_despesa.quantidade AS item_despesa_quantidade,"
                + " item_despesa.valor_unitario AS item_despesa_valor_unitario,"
                + " item_despesa.produto_id AS item_despesa_produto_id,"
                + " item_despesa.pedido_id AS item_despesa_pedido_id," + " ocorrencia.id AS ocorrencia_id,"
                + " ocorrencia.descricao AS ocorrencia_descricao,"
                + " ocorrencia.condicao_tempo AS ocorrencia_condicao_tempo,"
                + " ocorrencia.data_ocorrencia AS ocorrencia_data_ocorrencia,"
                + " ocorrencia.numero_vitimas AS ocorrencia_numero_vitimas,"
                + " ocorrencia.periodo_ocorrencia AS ocorrencia_periodo_ocorrencia" + " FROM "
                + " cliente cliente INNER JOIN entrada_acidente entrada_acidente ON cliente.id = entrada_acidente.cliente_id"
                + " INNER JOIN item_despesa item_despesa ON entrada_acidente.id = item_despesa.pedido_id"
                + " INNER JOIN ocorrencia ocorrencia ON entrada_acidente.ocorrencia_id = ocorrencia.id"
                + " INNER JOIN condutor condutor ON ocorrencia.condutor_id = condutor.id"
                + " INNER JOIN despesa despesa ON item_despesa.produto_id = despesa.id";
    }
```

query adicionando o "where data"

```
     public String getData(String dataI, String dataF) {
        return dataParaQuery = " where  entrada_acidente.data_criacao between '" + dataI + "'" + "and '" + dataF + "' "
                + "";
    }
```

Método que gera o relatório:

```
public void execute() throws ParseException {
        JasperReportBuilder report = DynamicReports.report();
        configure(report);
        convert();
        report.setDataSource(getQueryPrincipal(queryPrincipal) + getData(dataI, dataF), con);

        ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext.getResponse();

        try {
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            report.toPdf(response.getOutputStream());
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

xhtml (atualizado update2):

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/template/LayoutPadrao.xhtml"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">


<ui:define name="titulo">Relatório de entradas emitidas</ui:define>

<ui:define name="corpo">
    <h:form id="frm" acceptcharset="ISO-8859-1" >
        <h1>Relatório de entradas emitidas</h1>

        <p:messages autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />

        <p:toolbar style="margin-top: 20px">
            <p:toolbarGroup>
                <p:commandButton value="EmitirPdf"
                    action="#{relatorioEntradasBean.emitirPdf}" ajax="false" />
                <p:commandButton value="EmitirXls"
                    action="#{relatorioEntradasBean.emitirXls}" ajax="false" />
            </p:toolbarGroup>
            <p:toolbarGroup>
                <h:commandButton action="#{simpleReport.execute}" value="show pdf" />
            </p:toolbarGroup>
            <p:toolbarGroup>
                <h:commandLink value="Click here"
                    action="#{simpleReport.addtoList(nome)}">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{simpleReport.nome}"
                        value="nome" />
                </h:commandLink>
            </p:toolbarGroup>
            <p:toolbarGroup>
                <h:inputText id="nome" value="#{simpleReport.nome}" />
            </p:toolbarGroup>

            <p:toolbarGroup>
                <h:inputText binding="#{nome}" />
                <h:commandButton value="Test"
                    action="#{simpleReport.addtoList(nome.value)}" />
            </p:toolbarGroup>

        </p:toolbar>

        <p:panelGrid columns="7" id="painel"
            style="width: 100%; margin-top: 20px" columnClasses="rotulo, campo">
            <p:outputLabel value="Data de criação" />
            <h:panelGroup>
                <p:calendar value="#{simpleReport.dataInicialQuery}"
                    label="Data inicial" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" size="8" />
                <p:spacer width="8" />
                <h:outputText value="a" />
                <p:spacer width="8" />
                <p:calendar value="#{simpleReport.dataFinalQuery}"
                    label="Data final" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" size="8" />
            </h:panelGroup>
            <h:panelGroup>
                <p:outputLabel value="Cliente" for="cliente" />
                <p:autoComplete id="cliente" size="40" dropdown="true"
                    value="#{simpleReport.cliente}"
                    completeMethod="#{simpleReport.completarCliente}" var="cliente"
                    itemLabel="#{cliente.nome}" itemValue="#{cliente}"
                    forceSelection="true" />
            </h:panelGroup>


            <p:outputLabel value="Status" />
            <h:panelGroup>
                <p:selectOneMenu id="statusEntrada"
                    value="#{relatorioEntradasBean.statusEntrada}">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{enumProviderStatus.statusEntradas}"
                        var="statusEntrada" itemValue="#{statusEntrada}"
                        itemLabel="#{statusEntrada.descricao}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

Update2:
métodos para receber e concatenar os nomes vindos da página jsf:

```
private ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();

public void addtoList(String nome) {
        test.add(nome);
    }

    public String nomesParaQuery(String queryNome) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("and cliente.nome IN (");
        boolean added = false;
        for (String s : test) {
            if (added) {
                sb.append(",");
            }
            sb.append("'");
            sb.append(s);
            sb.append("'");
            added = true;
        }
        sb.append(")");
        queryNome = sb.toString();
        return queryNome;
    }
```

Método que gera o relatório:

```
public void execute() throws ParseException {
        JasperReportBuilder report = DynamicReports.report();
        configure(report);
        convert();
        report.setDataSource(getQueryPrincipal(queryPrincipal) + getData(dataI, dataF) + nomesParaQuery(queryNome),
                con);
                ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext.getResponse();

        try {
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            report.toPdf(response.getOutputStream());
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

clienteConverter:

```
package com.rodrigo.controleacidentes.converter;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;

import com.rodrigo.controleacidentes.model.Cliente;
import com.rodrigo.controleacidentes.repository.Clientes;
import com.rodrigo.controleacidentes.util.cdi.CDIServiceLocator;

@FacesConverter(forClass=Cliente.class)
public class ClienteConverter implements Converter {

    //@Inject
    private Clientes clientes;

    public ClienteConverter() {
        this.clientes = (Clientes) CDIServiceLocator.getBean(Clientes.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        Cliente retorno = null;

        if (value != null) {
            retorno = this.clientes.porId(new Long(value));
        }

        return retorno;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (value != null) {
            Cliente cliente = (Cliente) value;
            return cliente.getId() == null ? null : cliente.getId().toString();
        }
        return "";
    }

}
```

simpleReport:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class SimpleReport implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Date date = null;
    Connection con = new SQLConnection().getConnection();
    String dataInicialQuery;
    String dataFinalQuery;
    String queryPrincipal = "";
    String dataI = "";
    String dataF = "";
    private Cliente cliente;
    String dataParaQuery = "";
    String queryNome = "";
    private ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();
    String queryConcatenadaNome = "";
    private String nome = "";
    @Inject
    private Clientes clientes;

    public void addCliente(SelectEvent event) {
        String value = (String) event.getObject();
        System.out.println("selected " + value);

System.out.println("classe: " + event.getObject().getClass().toString());

    }

    public void addtoList(String cliente) {
        test.add(cliente);
        System.out.println(cliente);
    }

    public String nomesParaQuery(String queryNome) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("and cliente.id IN (");
        boolean added = false;
        for (String s : test) {
            if (added) {
                sb.append(",");
            }
            sb.append("'");
            sb.append(s);
            sb.append("'");
            added = true;
        }
        sb.append(")");
        queryNome = sb.toString();
        return queryNome;
    }

    public String getData(String dataI, String dataF) {
        return dataParaQuery = " where  entrada_acidente.data_criacao between '" + dataI + "'" + "and '" + dataF + "' "
                + "";
    }

    public String getQueryPrincipal(String queryPrincipal) {
        return queryPrincipal = "SELECT  cliente.id AS cliente_id,"
                + " cliente.doc_receita_federal AS cliente_doc_receita_federal," + "  cliente.email AS cliente_email,"
                + " cliente.nome AS cliente_nome," + "  cliente.tipo AS cliente_tipo," + "  condutor.id AS condutor_id,"
                + " condutor.codigo AS condutor_codigo," + "  condutor.nome AS condutor_nome,"
                + " despesa.id AS despesa_id," + " despesa.nome AS despesa_nome," + "   despesa.sku AS despesa_sku,"
                + " despesa.categoria_id AS despesa_categoria_id," + "  entrada_acidente.id AS entrada_acidente_id,"
                + " entrada_acidente.attach AS entrada_acidente_attach,"
                + " entrada_acidente.data_criacao AS entrada_acidente_data_criacao,"
                + " entrada_acidente.fileName AS entrada_acidente_fileName,"
                + " entrada_acidente.forma_pagamento AS entrada_acidente_forma_pagamento,"
                + " entrada_acidente.observacao AS entrada_acidente_observacao,"
                + " entrada_acidente.status AS entrada_acidente_status,"
                + " entrada_acidente.valor_desconto AS entrada_acidente_valor_desconto,"
                + " entrada_acidente.valor_total AS entrada_acidente_valor_total,"
                + " entrada_acidente.cliente_id AS entrada_acidente_cliente_id,"
                + " entrada_acidente.ocorrencia_id AS entrada_acidente_ocorrencia_id,"
                + " entrada_acidente.vendedor_id AS entrada_acidente_vendedor_id,"
                + " entrada_acidente.valor_unitario AS entrada_acidente_valor_unitario,"
                + " entrada_acidente.quantidade AS entrada_acidente_quantidade,"
                + " item_despesa.id AS item_despesa_id," + "  item_despesa.quantidade AS item_despesa_quantidade,"
                + " item_despesa.valor_unitario AS item_despesa_valor_unitario,"
                + " item_despesa.produto_id AS item_despesa_produto_id,"
                + " item_despesa.pedido_id AS item_despesa_pedido_id," + " ocorrencia.id AS ocorrencia_id,"
                + " ocorrencia.descricao AS ocorrencia_descricao,"
                + " ocorrencia.condicao_tempo AS ocorrencia_condicao_tempo,"
                + " ocorrencia.data_ocorrencia AS ocorrencia_data_ocorrencia,"
                + " ocorrencia.numero_vitimas AS ocorrencia_numero_vitimas,"
                + " ocorrencia.periodo_ocorrencia AS ocorrencia_periodo_ocorrencia" + " FROM "
                + " cliente cliente INNER JOIN entrada_acidente entrada_acidente ON cliente.id = entrada_acidente.cliente_id"
                + " INNER JOIN item_despesa item_despesa ON entrada_acidente.id = item_despesa.pedido_id"
                + " INNER JOIN ocorrencia ocorrencia ON entrada_acidente.ocorrencia_id = ocorrencia.id"
                + " INNER JOIN condutor condutor ON ocorrencia.condutor_id = condutor.id"
                + " INNER JOIN despesa despesa ON item_despesa.produto_id = despesa.id";
    }

    public void convert() throws ParseException {

        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("BRT"));
        DateFormat utcFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
        Date dInicial = df.parse(dataInicialQuery);
        Date dFinal = df.parse(dataFinalQuery);
        System.out.println("DateD: " + dInicial);
        String dataInicialUTC = utcFormat.format(dInicial);
        String dataFinalUTC = utcFormat.format(dFinal);
        System.out.println("dataInicialUTC:" + (dataInicialUTC));
        System.out.println("dataFinalUTC:" + (dataFinalUTC));

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        dataI = sdf.format(dInicial);
        dataF = sdf.format(dFinal);
        System.out.println("New Date:" + (dataI));
        System.out.println("New Date:" + (dataF));

    }

    private void configure(JasperReportBuilder report) {
        report.setTemplate(Template.reportTemplate)
                .columns(
                        col.column("Cliente", "cliente_nome", type.stringType())
                                .setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER),
                        col.column("Status", "entrada_acidente_status", type.stringType())
                                .setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER),
                        col.column("Valor", "entrada_acidente_valor_unitario", type.bigDecimalType())
                                .setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER))
                .title(Template.createTitleComponent("Relatório")).pageFooter(Template.footerComponent);
    }

    public void execute() throws ParseException {
        JasperReportBuilder report = DynamicReports.report();
        configure(report);
        convert();
        report.setDataSource(getQueryPrincipal(queryPrincipal) + getData(dataI, dataF) + nomesParaQuery(queryNome),
                con);
        System.out.println("Name:" + nome);
        System.out.println(
                "QQQ:" + getQueryPrincipal(queryPrincipal) + getData(dataI, dataF) + nomesParaQuery(queryNome));
        ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext.getResponse();

        try {
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            report.toPdf(response.getOutputStream());
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String getDataInicialQuery() {
        return dataInicialQuery;
    }

    public void setDataInicialQuery(String dataInicialQuery) {
        this.dataInicialQuery = dataInicialQuery;
    }

    public String getDataFinalQuery() {
        return dataFinalQuery;
    }

    public Cliente getCliente() {
        return cliente;
    }

    public void setCliente(Cliente cliente) {
        this.cliente = cliente;
    }

    public void setDataFinalQuery(String dataFinalQuery) {
        this.dataFinalQuery = dataFinalQuery;
    }

    public List<Cliente> completarCliente(String nome) {
        return this.clientes.porNome(nome);
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem algumas formas de se fazer o que você quer no jasper reports:

**1 - Continuar usando a consulta no relatório e passar uma lista de clientes como parâmetro**

Você hoje passa como parâmetros um mapa onde você informa:

```
Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<>();
parametros.put("data_inicio", this.dataInicio);
parametros.put("data_fim", this.dataFim);
parametros.put("nome_cliente", this.cliente);
```

A primeira solução consiste em não passar somente um cliente e sim uma lista de clientes, por exemplo o id deles em uma variável String que será substituída na sua consulta, por exemplo:

```
 Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<>();
 parametros.put("clientes", "('1', '2', '3', '4')");
```

Esta string seria preenchida dinamicamente é claro e na consulta do relatório você modificaria para algo como:

```
...
WHERE
     entrada_acidente.`data_criacao` BETWEEN $P{data_inicio} AND $P{data_fim}
 AND cliente.id IN $P{clientes}
 AND entrada_acidente.`status` = $P{status_entrada}
...
```

**2 - Usar um datasource ao invés de deixar o relatório executar a consulta**

A ideia desta abordagem seria passar o datasource para o relatório usando o método

```
fillReport(java.io.InputStream inputStream, java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object> parameters, JRDataSource dataSource)
```

Este data por ser de vários tipos, uma lista de objetos ou até mesmo a o result Set. Para montá-lo seria da seguinte maneira:

```
ResultSet rsRelatorio = dao.executaConsultaRelatorioClientes(); //apenas para ilustrar, aqui executa a consulta e retorna o resultSet.
JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(relatorioStream, this.parametros, connection, new JRResultSetDataSource(rsRelatorio));
```

Nesta abordagem você também teria que modificar a sua consulta de maneira que carregue vários clientes.

Existem outras formas, mas em todas elas você deverá fazer uma mudança na sua consulta ou na fonte de dados de maneira que carregue os clientes de acordo com o que você definir.

Comment: Acredito que entendi, vou verificar, entretanto, neste meio tempo em que fiz a pergunta, como não consegui avançar, procurei sobre o `DynamicReports` que também usa o `JasperReports` ( num projeto web), pois havia usado em desktop. Na minha opnião ele é mais " prático" ao menos em partes por não precisar do jrxml, envia-se tudo da classe java, colunas, parâmetros etc....Vou  guardar sua resposta , e dependendo dos resultados no `DynamicReports` eu retorno a esta abordagem. Obrigado por enquanto.

Comment: adicionei os códigos conforme a nova abordagem (Updade1), creio que tem algo a ver com sua segunda sugestão, poderia dar uma olhada? Agora não tenho mais o jrxml, e passo as colunas e dados necessários direto da  classe java. Permanece a dificuldade em colocar esta lista de clientes "na query". Além de enviar estes clientes da página jsf.

Comment: @Rodrigo está um pouco difícil de entender o seu problema. Acredito que fique até complicado para discutir por aqui. Criei uma sala de reunião no chat do stack para isso http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46019/parametros-no-jasper-reports. Acho que você nunca acessou o chat, porque não consegui te convidar. Acesse este link e comente aqui que eu convido novamente.

Comment: Acessei o link.